# AWS CodePipeline cannot create Device Farm- Custom test environment

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-device-farm

I am working with AWS cloud. in AWS Device Farm console, I can select custom test environment

device farm custom environment

[image: 1]

But when run via AWS CodePipeline, It's cannot.

Because I am running iOS testNG. in custom test environment is normal but standard test environment is show "No such element".

Comment: this is log mesage:
login failed: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'ip-192-168-11-5.us-west-2.compute.internal', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c38:ec67:875e:285b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '12.0.2' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver Capabilities